# Math.Cos(x)<-1 with large values of x

Tags: c#, monodevelop

I wrote very simple code:

```
public static void Main (string[] args)
{       
    String str="1,0992748756871115E+41"; //yes, I know that is very large value

    Double x=Convert.ToDouble(str);

    Double res=Math.Cos(x);

    Double resRound=Math.Round(res);

    Console.WriteLine("x={0}\nres={1}\nresRound={2}", x, res, resRound);
}
```

And this code output very large value of res value: `1,09927487568711E+41` which a equals to Math.Cos's arguments:
[image: screen]

I thought, that is a bug of `Gtk#` and decided to test what value returns this code compilled by .NET Framework and it returned same value!
Is that so the meaning of the function cos(x) exceeds the limits of segment from `-1` to `1`? How does it possible?

Comment: It means the the function isn't precise at such high magnitudes.

Comment: You can just mod the value by 2*PI and take the COS of that...

Comment: @Servy: Not really; the result would be completely meaningless.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Well, yeah, given that `double` doesn't have sufficient precision to represent the digits that actually matter.  Didn't think about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.cos.aspx):

> Acceptable values of d range from approximately -9223372036854775295 to approximately 9223372036854775295. For values outside this range, the Cos method returns d unchanged rather than throwing an exception.

Comment: Thank you. But what the reason to make it?

Comment: @Mixim: Because numbers of this size no longer have the precision to make the calculation of `cos`, etc. meaningful.

Answer (score -1):

You can break down the expression to get the values like

Cost(A+B)= CosA *CosB -SinA * SinB

Break down as low as you can get within the documentation limit

Comment: That will not help.  A `double` simply doesn't have enough precision to make these calculations meaningful.

Comment: Yes you can...just divide your number by 2 and continue to do that until u get below the limit,  when you divide if there is a remainder, put it in one of the numbers  like
   cos (7) = cos3 *cos4 -sin3 *sin4   ....do the same ...

Comment: You can do that, but the calculation won't tell you anything useful; with an input of 1e41 (as in the OP's example), the error is roughly 1e25.